# should an applet or an application catch Error exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

should an applet or an application catch Error exceptions?

I think both can do it.

any help?

Answer (score 2):

No. `Error`s are runtime errors that are outside of your control (eg, `OutOfMemoryError`).

`Error`s are unchecked. You don't need to catch them or declare them, because they can happen at literally any point in your application. And, when they happen, it means that the sky is falling, and nothing you do will fix them.

In fact, in certain cases, you can't do anything safely at all. If the computer is out of memory, you likely can't even log it.

So, it's best not to worry about them.